# Looking for a tutorial about setting up Bitbucket with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I'm a newbie in distributed source control systems and have only used SourceSafe before. I'm very eager to use Bitbucket.org as the repository of my source codes and my IDE is VS 2010. I'm looking for a tutorial for setting up and using Bitbucket with VS but any tutorial I checked (including below links) are out-dated and the instructions mentioned there do not exist and/or compatible with current versions of Visual HG and Tortorise HG.

http://www.basarat.com/2011/01/setting-up-mercurial-repository-with.html

http://blog.ahmadhirbawi.net/blog/post/2010/10/30/Online-Source-Control-Bitbucket-Mercurial-and-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-20082010-Integration.aspx

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/bitbucket-users/-bTm5YX3bdE

Can you please suggest some updated materials for using Bitbucket with VS 2010?

Comment: Maybe it is better to suggest me an edit instead of voting to close without a comment.

Comment: What part is not working? I looked at the first link that you posted and it looks right to me.  What version of Visual Studio are you using? VisualHg doesn't work with the express editions.

Comment: @Farshid if you need help editing / writing questions, have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), or [this excellent checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Note though that Stack Overflow is not quite the place for "Suggest tutorial for X" questions, which will usually be closed. If you need more help or info you can always [ask on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).